# Shell function parameter

Tags: linux, shell, parameters

Is there a way to declare and pass parameters for shell functions, like so ?

```
function msg( m )
{
   read -p "Task #" + m + "done. Press any key to continue
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you didn't specify which shell, but assuming bash (or zsh):

```
function msg() {
     read -p "Task #${1} done. Press any key to continue"
}
```

and then you just use it like

```
% msg "foobar"
```

with `$0` - `$X` you acces the nth parameter, in `$*` and `$@` you find the whole line. just check the manual of your shell.